# Oracle: How to use regexp_substr in this case

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table in Oracle where one of the column contains UserIds which are in the form of \. For eg "fin\george", "sales\andy" etc. How can I use REGEXP_SUBSTR function to get only the  from the UserIds. ie I want to fetch only "george", "andy" etc. I have achieved the desired reult using SUBSTR function but I want to use REGEXP_SUBSTR in this case.

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('fin\george','\[^\]+,') "UserName" FROM DUAL;
```

but it did'nt help. Can anyone please point out my mistake ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to use a `regexp_replace` with a backreference.  I'm assuming that all the characters before and after the `\` are alphabetic.  If you allow numbers, you'd want to use the `[[:alnum:]]` rather than `[[:alpha::]`.

```
  1* SELECT REGEXP_replace('fin\george',
                           '([[:alpha:]]+\\)([[:alpha:]]+)$', 
                           '\2') "UserName" 
       FROM DUAL
SQL> /

UserNa
------
george
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace( 'fin\george', '.*\\', null ) from dual;
```

returns `george`.

The regex will match any character followed by the `\` (which is escaped), as many times as possible (greedy).
So it will match everything up to the final `\`.
Then the matching string is replaced with `null`.

`null` is the default so

```
select regexp_replace('fin\george', '.*\\' ) from dual;
```

does the same thing

Same expression can extract filename from the end of pathname e.g.

```
select regexp_replace ('fin\fin2\fin3\fin4\george', '.*\\' ) from dual;
```

will also return `george`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('fin\george', '[^\]+', 1, 2) AS userId from dual;

USERID
------
george
```

See [this Oracle Base article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/regular-expressions-support-in-oracle.php)

Comment: Stack Overflow was removing \ because it is an escape character. You can highlight your code and click `{}` to mark something up as code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use escaping: \\ instead of \

Comment: Doing that would give this output: "\george"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (IMHO) to do this is the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('fin\george', '[^\\]+$') AS "UserName" FROM DUAL;
```

The issues with your original query were (a) that the `\` character was not escaped and (b) there was an extraneous comma in the regular expression. I've used the end-of-string anchor `$` here, assuming that there are not more than two elements delimited by `\`. If there are more than two, and you need only the second one, you can use the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('fin\george\ringo', '[^\\]+', 1, 2) AS "UserName"
  FROM DUAL;
```

This tells Oracle to start looking at the first character of the string and return the second match.